# Cardinality of sets within a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Take $A = \{\text{Asia}, \text{Europe}, \text{Africa}\}$, $B = \{\{\text{Asia}\}, \text{Europe}, \text{Africa}\}$ and $C =\{\text{Dry}, \text{Cold}\}$.

$P(B \cup A)$ would be $5$, since there is another set in $B$, correct?

$P(B \cup C)$ would be $5$ as well.

Comment: If you're using "P" to mean the cardinality of the set, $P(A\cup B)$ (usually $|A\cup B|$) would be four.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re using $P(X)$ to mean the cardinality of $X$, then

$$B\cup A=\big\{\{\text{Asia}\},\text{Europe},\text{Africa},\text{Asia}\big\}\;,$$

so $P(B\cup A)=4$, not $5$. However, $P(B\cup C)$ is $5$:

$$B\cup C=\big\{\{\text{Asia}\},\text{Europe},\text{Africa},\text{Dry},\text{Cold}\big\}\;.$$